# How to set action in .js file scope to get it on other .js file scope: I'm not geting action on other js file

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, xml

1. ptgrid.js
       I have written deleteQuote() function in ptgrid.js file. and another save is written in screen.js
       Problem: I'm unable get updated action on screen.js

   ```
   function deleteQuote(data, rootscope, scope){

       var parentScope =
           (angular.element('#Quote_Search').size() != 0)
               ? angular.element('#Quote_Search').scope().$parent
               : angular.element('#Quote_Search_Advanced').scope().$parent;
       var screenScope =
           (angular.element('#Quote_Search').size() != 0)
               ? angular.element('#Quote_Search').scope()
               : angular.element('#Quote_Search_Advanced').scope();

       parentScope.actionName  = "Delete";

        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this quote?")){

            data.REQUESTCODE = 'QUTPROCSDELRq';
            data.BC_KEY_LOCATION_COMPANY = data.BCLOCATION;
            data.BC_KEY_MASTER_COMPANY = data.BCMASTER0CO;
            data.BC_KEY_POLICY_NUMBER = data.BCPOLICY0NUM;
            data.BC_KEY_MODULE = data.BCMODULE;
            data.BC_KEY_SYMBOL = data.BCSYMBOL;
            data.BC_AGENT_NUMBER = data.BCAGENCY;
            data.PROC_REQ_TYPE = "DL";
            if(screenScope.data.SYMBOL != undefined && screenScope.data.SYMBOL != ""){
                data.SYMBOL = parentScope.SYMBOL = screenScope.data.SYMBOL;
            }
            if(screenScope.data.POLICY0NUM != undefined && screenScope.data.POLICY0NUM != ""){
                data.POLICY0NUM = parentScope.POLICY0NUM = screenScope.data.POLICY0NUM;
            }
            if(screenScope.data.MODULE != undefined && screenScope.data.MODULE != ""){
                data.MODULE = parentScope.MODULE = screenScope.data.MODULE;
            }
            if(screenScope.data.LASTNAME != undefined && screenScope.data.LASTNAME != ""){
                data.LASTNAME = parentScope.LASTNAME = screenScope.data.LASTNAME;
            }
            if(screenScope.data.FIRSTNAME != undefined && screenScope.data.FIRSTNAME != ""){
                data.FIRSTNAME = parentScope.FIRSTNAME = screenScope.data.FIRSTNAME;
            }
            if(screenScope.data.SSN != undefined && screenScope.data.SSN != ""){
                data.SSN = parentScope.SSN = screenScope.data.SSN;
            }
            if(screenScope.data.CUST0NO != undefined && screenScope.data.CUST0NO != ""){
                data.CUST0NO = parentScope.CUST0NO = screenScope.data.CUST0NO;
            }
            parentScope.data=data;
            parentScope.save(parentScope.data);

        }
   }
   ```
2. Screen.js

   ```
   $scope.save = function (method) {
           if($scope.currentScreenId){
               var data=angular.element("#"+$scope.currentScreenId).scope().data;
               angular.extend($scope.data,data);
           }
           ScopeData.set($scope.data);
           //$rootScope.data.method = method;
           if($scope.actionName != "Search"){      
               return save($browser, $location, $rootScope, $scope, Data, MetaData, ViewState, SupportData, $routeParams, ScopeData);
           }
       };
   ```